# Counting failure probabilities of other contestants alongwith odds in favour

Tags: probability

Say a horserace(ties are impossible) involves four horses A, B, C, and D, with the odds in their favour being $1:3,1:4,1:5,$ and $1:6$ respectively. Now to find the chances of one of them winning the race, the method I initially thought of(the correct one) is adding their individual probabilities of success; $$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}$$
But then there's this- when you're finding the probability of success of one horse, shouldn't you take the product of its chances of success with the other horses' chances of failure? Why is doing that wrong here?

Comment: Let's stop to think about this for a moment. Forget the numbers. You say that you have four horses in a race. And the question is: What is the probability that one of them wins? Think about it ... What is the probability that none of them wins? I mean ... Someone has to win the race, right?

Comment: I don't know what to say.... Delete this?

Comment: @MattiP.: Wait, no! The race doesn't necessarily involve *just* these four horses! The question I got this from just says 'In a given race, the odds in favour of four horses A, B, C, and D are 1:3....assuming a tie is impossible, find the chance that one of them wins the race'. So these are just the horses that we have data on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the events of the horses winning be $\{A,B,C,D\}$. Let $E$ be the event any other horse wins.

Note that $A\cap B = A\cap C = A\cap D= A\cap E = B\cap C = B\cap D= B\cap E= C \cap D = C \cap E = D\cap E = \varnothing$. The only events with positive probability are
\begin{array}{c}
A\cap B^C\cap C^C\cap D^C\cap E^C\\
A^C\cap B\cap C^C\cap D^C\cap E^C\\ 
A^C\cap B^C\cap C\cap D^C\cap E^C\\
A^C\cap B^C\cap C^C\cap D\cap E^C\\
A^C\cap B^C\cap C^C\cap D^C\cap E\\
\end{array}

Further, these events are disjoint. Therefore $\mathbb P[A] = \mathbb P[A\cap B^C\cap C^C\cap D^C\cap E^C]$ and similarly for other horses. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, so I wouldn't be able to *multiply* the probabilities of the other horses losing with the probability of A winning, because they're dependent, right? Also, the last equation makes intuitive sense; so if we knew the conditional probability values and plugged them in, we would get the rhs to equal P(A), but since that's a lot of work involving values we don't have, we just use P(A). Have I got it right?

Comment: please respond.

Comment: 1) "so I wouldn't be able to multiply the probabilities of the other horses losing with the probability of A winning, because they're dependent, right" Yes A wins implies the other loses. 2) There is no need to use conditional probabilities for this question, but in any case here's the conditional probability $\mathbb P(A|B=1) = \mathbb P(C|B=1) = \mathbb P(D|B=1) = \mathbb P(E|B=1) = 0$. You might similarly construct some other conditionals. But these would not be required for this question as the sets are disjoint

Comment: so 1) indeed your original hypothesis that probability that one of them wins is the sum of the probabilities from their odds is correct------- 2) "probability of success of one horse, shouldn't you take the product of its chances of success with the other horses' chances of failure" The precise formulation of this is $P[A\wedge B^c]\stackrel{?}{=}P[A]P[B^C]=P[A](1-P[B])$, and the answer is no, as they are not independent.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time.